# Pandey and Dubey estimator.

Tags: sampling, unbiased-estimator, proof, estimators, mse

I am studying sampling theory

Pandey and Dubey(1988) proposed the following product estimator.

$\bar y_{PD} = \bar y \left( \frac{\bar x + C_x}{\bar X +C_x}\right)$

And its Mean square error is equal to

$MSE(\bar y_{PD})= \frac{1-f}{n} \bar Y^2 [ C_y^2 \theta^2 C_x^2 +2\theta \rho C_x C_y]$

where $\theta =\frac{\bar X}{\bar X + C_x}$

But I want to learn the way of getting (proving) MSE of the estimator?

Can any one show this? Or suggest a journal or book containing the proof.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Have you tried just pushing it through the formula? I.e.,

Comment: $$MSE(\bar y_{PD})=\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar y_{PD}-y)^2$$

Comment: Now, $\hat R_{PD}= \frac{\bar x +C_x}{\bar X +C_x}$ so, $R_{PD}= \frac{\bar X +C_x}{\bar X +C_x}$ i.e. $R_{PD}=1$ I'm confused in this point @zero

Comment: $MSE(\bar y_{PD}= \frac{1-f}{n}(S_y^2 - 2R_{PD} S_{yx} +R_{PD}^2 S_x^2$. I am solving this by using the equation. Dear @zero please help me:)